# Wordpress assets upload folder

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

is it possible in wordpress to define a different uploadfolder for assets like pageheaders and logo's?

I'd like to seperate the whole logo's and headers uploads from the default media upload section.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin - [Custom Upload Dir](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/)

I needed similar thing in the past and this plugin did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks, I did find this too, but wasn't sure it would be doing what I needed. Think I will use it then :)